# Can a holder of carta soggiorno travel to U.K. Without a visa With his spouse holding an Italian passport

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, eu

please I'm confuse. I need your help. I want to find out if a carta soggiorno holder can travel to U.K. Without a visa whiles going with her spouse who holds Italian passport.

Comment: You can use this https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa to check if you need a visa.

Answer (score 0):

To add to what @Traveller mentioned, there is such a thing called an EU/EEA family permit for the UK which is free of charge: https://www.gov.uk/family-permit
(you'd obviously have to prove your relationship with your Italian spouse - marriage certificate / proof of living together / etc.).